# "Derivations" and Runge's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that for a given region $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ and a continous linear operator $D\in\mathcal{C}(\mathcal{H}(\Omega))$ satisfying Leibniz's rule
$$D(fg)=fD(g)+D(f)g, \qquad\forall f,g\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega),$$
there exists an holomorphic function $h\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$, such that
for any $f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$
$$D(f)=f'\cdot h.$$

The problem says that I should use Runge's theorem, but I don't see how. By now, I have taken a compact disk $\overline{D}:=\overline{D(a,R)}\subset\Omega$ and used the analytic expression of $f$ over $D$ to obtain
$$\Phi(f)=\Phi\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{(z-a)^n}{n!}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}\Phi((z-a)^n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}n(z-a)^{n-1}\Phi(z-a)=$$
$$=\Phi(z-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n-1!}(z-a)^{n-1}=\Phi(z-a)\cdot f'.$$
Since $\Phi(z-a)\in\mathcal{H}(D)$ and $f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$, all that we have to do is apply the analytic continuation theorem and we obtain the result. What is wrong with my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. By virtue of Runge's Theorem, it suffices to show that, there exists an $h\in\mathcal H(\Omega)$, such that
$$
D(z^n)=nz^{n-1}h(z)\quad\text{and} \quad D\left(\frac{1}{(z-a)^n}\right) =-\frac{nh(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}},
$$
for all $a\ne\in\Omega$.

Set first, $h(z)=D(z)$. Clearly, $D(z^n)=nz^{n-1}h(z)$, inductively, and
$$
0=D\left((z-a)\cdot\frac{1}{z-a}\right)=(z-a)h(z)\cdot\frac{1}{z-a}+D\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right),
$$
and hence
$$
D\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right) =-\frac{h(z)}{(z-a)^2}.
$$

Comment: So you show that it is true for rational functions and then use the fact that each holomorphic function can be approached by rational functions (Runge's theorem), right?

Comment: According to Runge's Theorem, that's enough.